# Not able to download mmcv 1.3.0 and build wheels

Tags: python, machine-learning, anaconda, conda

When I try to install `mmcv-full==1.3.0`, it couldn't be downloaded and build the wheel (where I have updated to wheel already)

[image]

error Could not build wheels for mmcv-full, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
[image]

But then when I try to use
`mim install mmcv-full`

error message:

```
RROR: Failed building wheel for mmcv-full
  Running setup.py clean for mmcv-full
Failed to build mmcv-full
ERROR: Could not build wheels for mmcv-full, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

The latest version of `mmcv-full` could be downloaded, but as the repo I am trying to clone needs to use `mmcv version 1.3.0`.
I am using `Windows 11` and would like to know how should I download the version.

Thank you so much.

Comment: Images should not be used to display text. Please edit.

Answer (score 0):

## Issue

This error happens when you may not have a pre-built package corresponding to CUDA or Pytorch or MMCV version.

## Solution

In this situation, you can build `MMCV` from source by following the [MMCV build official guide](https://mmcv.readthedocs.io/en/latest/get_started/build.html).